# How to name train + validation set

Tags: cross-validation, terminology, validation, train-test-split

Usually in machine learning pipelines, we use a train set, a validation set and a test set. Quite often, we first split the test set from the rest, and then we split the "rest" into train and validation sets (possibly multiple times if using cross-validation).

What would be the proper way to name the "rest" (the set that contains data dedicated for training and validation)? Train_val_set? Education_set?

Comment: I don’t see this as opinion-based. It’s a terminology question, looking for a canonical name. I believe it should be reopened.